# .NET class private member oddity - null value not reflected?

Tags: vb.net, class, reference

I have the following 2 classes to illustrate the problem I ran into.

**Note: GetRandomString(int length) creates a random string.**

```
Public Class PrivateFieldNullTest

    Public Sub NullTestClass()
        _testClass = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private _testClass As TestClass
    Public Property GetTestClass() As TestClass
        Get
            If _testClass Is Nothing Then
                _testClass = New TestClass()
                _testClass.TestString = GetRandomString(5)
            End If

            Return _testClass
        End Get

        Set(value As TestClass)
            _testClass = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class TestClass
    Public Property TestString() As String
End Class
```

I then use the following code to call the classes above:

**Note: CheckIsSame is a literal control.**

```
Private Sub NullTest()

    Dim toc As New PrivateFieldNullTest()

    Dim tc = toc.GetTestClass

    CheckIsSame.Text &= String.Format("NullTest - Before nullify '{0}';", tc.TestString)

    toc.NullTestClass()

    CheckIsSame.Text &= String.Format(" After nullify '{0}';", tc.TestString)
    CheckIsSame.Text &= String.Format(" new test string after Nullify '{0}';", toc.GetTestClass.TestString)
End Sub
```

And it prints out the following:

*NullTest - Before nullify '**IZIBD**'; After nullify '**IZIBD**'; new test string after Nullify 'RLKHQ';*

I wonder why the values for before nullify and after nullify are the same.

The call toc.NullTestClass() set the private field _testClass to null, but somehow the reference **tc** in the calling code survives after the function call.

I'd expect the second tc.TestString to produce an error.

Comment: Each reference is independent. That's the nature of references. Both `_testClass` and `tc` end up referencing the *same* object. What happens to `_testClass` after that has *no* effect on `tc`.

Comment: I see... the reference itself can be set to null, but the "object" cannot.

But if I replace the toc.NullTestClass() call with
toc.GetTestClass.TestString = GetRandomString(5)

then the before and after string will be different, because I update the value in the object...

Comment: How could an object be set to null?  That's like saying that this dog over here doesn't exist any more.  I might have a pet and then not have a pet and then have a pet again.  If I have no dog and then I get a dog and then I get rid of that dog and then get another dog, I've basically set my Pet property to null but that doesn't mean that the first dog ceased to exist.  Programming objects work like real-life objects, which is the whole point.